How to get data from [object File] in node.js
I've tried to upload image and send it to server to save it in an assigned directory. It is sent through node.js. The upload process is a typical XMLHttpRequest();
My HTML code:
<form id="choose-profile-img" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="avatar">Choose profile image</label>
    <input
        type="file"
        id="avatar"
        class="hidden"
        name="rawfile"
        accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
        multiple
    /><br/>
    <button>Upload</button>
</form>

At node.js server, I viewed the data as:
let data = parse(body);
console.log("Raw file:", data['rawfile']); // [object File]

So how do I extract data from [object File] or what is it?
If this is impossible, what is your suggestion for my further research.
Edit: To give you the better look, I don't don't use Express. I just created my own app. It look like:
if (req.method === 'POST') {
    let body = [];
    req.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
    }).on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        
        uploadFile(body, (result) => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
}

At the destination file:
const fs = require('fs');
const { parse } = require('querystring');

exports.uploadFile = (body, callback) => {
    let data = parse(body);
    
    // This is where I want write image file into a designated directory before I insert data into database
    console.log("Raw file:", data['rawfile']); // [object File]
    
    // Based on my research, browser cannot give the path to uploaded file
    // The readFile function requires file path, if I get it I won't have any problem
    
    user.find({ name: data.name }).then((doc)=>{
        if (!doc.length) {
            return;
        } else {
            // insert data into database
        }
    }).catch((err)=>{
        // handle the error
    });
};

So, it's pretty easy to build whole website with pure node.js. No Express is needed.

"The upload process is a typical XMLHttpRequest" - are you using js to create and POST a request rather than using the form submit?   In which case, it depends on you how formulate your XMLHttpRequest, which you've not included here.

@fdomn-m Yes, I use the POST method. But that isn't a problem. It get passed the process already. The data has reached the process I save into MongoDB database and save physical image into the a designated directory. And it's done. But I don't know how to get data from [object File] object.

what is it - [object File] means that js has converted an object to a string. In this case it's of type File.   eg console.log("" + data) -> [object Object] (depending on data).   So at some point in your process, the rawfile property/value has been converted to a string.

Please share more of your Node.js code. What is parse and how do you obtain the variable body?

@ Heiko Theißen The parse is const { parse } = require('querystring');

The file may inherit blob (https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39015). I used that before, but forgot the detail. Here is blob doc: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#class-blob

@fdomn-m I've tried to read it as below, it didn't work:
const content = fs.readFileSync(data['rawfile'], function(error, data) {
console.log("Data", data);
});

@ket, how does your Node.js server look? Is it based on Express or something else? How does the POST handler look?

Just do a console.log(data). You will get an useable output

@Thallius - I get all the data. All I need is a file, or a path to a file so I can write it to the directory I want -- this is a problem I look to solve. The problem is - how do I get the path to the uploaded file.

I think the way to go is as per suggested by @Peter Lai. I just have no idea about it now.
